# triangulate faces obj format problem

Tags: modeling, export, vertices, faces, obj

This is probably a noob question but here goes. I don't remember how to export correctly to my own obj parser.

this is how I want the faces to be exported (How they used to be exported correctly):

```
f 5/1/1 6/2/1 1/3/1
f 6/1/2 7/2/2 3/4/2
f 7/1/3 8/2/3 4/4/3
f 8/1/4 5/2/4 1/4/4
f 1/1/5 2/2/5 3/4/5
f 8/1/6 7/2/6 6/4/6
f 6/2/1 2/4/1 1/3/1
f 2/3/2 6/1/2 3/4/2
f 3/3/3 7/1/3 4/4/3
f 4/3/4 8/1/4 1/4/4
f 4/3/5 1/1/5 3/4/5
f 5/3/6 8/1/6 6/4/6
```

But everything I try with the exporter now only gives me something like this:

```
f 5//1 6//1 1//1
f 6//2 7//2 3//2
f 7//3 8//3 4//3
f 8//4 5//4 1//4
f 1//5 2//5 3//5
f 8//6 7//6 6//6
f 6//1 2//1 1//1
f 2//2 6//2 3//2
f 3//3 7//3 4//3
f 4//4 8//4 1//4
f 4//5 1//5 3//5
f 5//6 8//6 6//6
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried converting all quads in edit mode to triangles manually in vain, and tested all export variables. I've tried different versions of blender too.

Comment: I do believe this is the 15,000th question on this site!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! I did search for answears on the web but nothing worked. Would you kindly link me a few you know of?

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, this is I believe unique, just a milestone for those of us that are frequenters here.

Comment: Oh! I thought you were ironic! sorry! Wow thats really cool actually! :D

Comment: Kinda sad it was wasted on such an insignificant question :P

Comment: no question is insignificant , but unfortunately I have limited knowledge on the matter ... congrats blender.stackexchange and crew! 15000 questions hurray!

Comment: Well, it could have been *way* worse :), like a duplicate or a really poorly written question, which come along from time to time :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Wavefront file-format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex_Texture_Coordinate_Indices), the second number for every element for a face is the texture-coordinate

The quick way to get it running:
Select your object, go into edit-mode, press `U` and select `Unwrap`.
[image: 2]

When exporting, make sure you have `Include UVs` selected.

[image: 3]

Outcome (only faces):

```
f 2/1/1 3/2/1 4/3/1
f 8/1/2 7/2/2 6/3/2
f 5/1/3 6/2/3 2/3/3
f 6/1/4 7/2/4 3/3/4
f 3/4/5 7/1/5 8/2/5
f 1/1/6 4/2/6 8/3/6
f 1/4/1 2/1/1 4/3/1
f 5/4/2 8/1/2 6/3/2
f 1/4/3 5/1/3 2/3/3
f 2/4/4 6/1/4 3/3/4
f 4/3/5 3/4/5 8/2/5
f 5/4/6 1/1/6 8/3/6
```